# I can't understand why my query is not working

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, userlocation, geopoints, pfquery

so i have a bunch of objects on parse.com. class name is "MainInfo" with geo points in a column named geoPoint.

I am getting the users location by adding the following to my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFGeoPoint *userLocation;
```

Then adding the following to viewDidLoad:

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    self.userLocation = geoPoint;
    [self loadObjects];
}
}];
```

and performing the rolling queryForTable:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
// User's location
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = self.userLocation;
// Create a query for places
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MainInfo"];
// Interested in locations near user.
[query whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint];
// Limit what could be a lot of points.
query.limit = 10;
// Final list of objects
_placesObjects = [query findObjects];

return query;
}
```

Xcode gives me the error `*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: $nearSphere)`

I've got no idea what I am doing wrong, as far as I can see it should work.

I worked along with the parse documentation to get me this far. [Here is a link](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS)

Comment: Has `self.userLocation` been updated at the time?

Comment: @Wain no it hasn't been updated, how can i make the query wait until the user location is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises because you're passing a nil value to `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:` as `self.userLocation` is unlikely to be set the first time the view loads. You will want to do two things:

1. In your `queryForTable` method, check if `self.userLocation` is nil. If it is, return nil. This acts as a no-op and the table won't show any data just yet.

   ```
   - (PFQuery *)queryForTable
   {
       if (!self.userLocation) {
           return nil;
       }
       // User's location
       PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = self.userLocation;
       // Create a query for places
       PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MainInfo"];
       // Interested in locations near user.
       [query whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint];
       // Limit what could be a lot of points.
       query.limit = 10;
       // Final list of objects
       _placesObjects = [query findObjects];

       return query;
   }
   ```
2. In your `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:` completion block, once the `self.userLocation` value is set, you will want to call `[self loadObjects]`. This will tell the `PFQueryTableViewController` to run your query again, and this time around `self.userLocation` will not be nil, allowing you to construct your original query. Fortunately, you've already performed this step, but I've included it here in case anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 2):

When you make the `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` call it has a completion block. This completion block marks the point at which you have the required information to populate the table view (or you know that there is an error and you should do something else). So, you shouldn't display / load query data into the table view until the completion block is called. Other wise you don't have the required information to complete the query.

You could display an activity indicator while you're waiting. Or, it might be better to get the `userLocation` before even showing this view so you always have the information for the query when you get here.

Comment: How would I make the tableview wait until i get the location before the data is loaded?

Comment: You may be able to return `nil` from `queryForTable` and then call `reloadData` from the completion block once the real query can be created. Not sure if this will work perfectly - depends on the table view handling `nil`.